# SQLiteLog no such table in android using Sqllite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-like

[image]
By using assets folder, we are reading data i.e,address details based on search keyword:
Here is my code

```
 private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor c;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_search);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_search);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("sample", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);


    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            search_keyword = et_search.getText().toString();
            arr_data = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
            if (isValid()) {
               SELECT_SQL = "SELECT  ROWID AS _id,* FROM Addresses where Type LIKE '%" + search_keyword + "%'";

                Log.d("daatt",SELECT_SQL);
                try {
                    c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    showRecords();

                } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }
    });


}

private void showRecords() {

        String ugName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
        String ugaddress = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address"));
        String ugtype = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Type"));

        ListItems items = new ListItems();

        // Finish reading one raw, now we have to pass them to the POJO
        items.setName(ugName);
        items.setAddress(ugaddress);
        items.setType(ugtype);

        // Lets pass that POJO to our ArrayList which contains undergraduates as type
        arr_data.add(items);
    }
    ListDataAdapter adapter = new ListDataAdapter(arr_data);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
        int count = c.getCount();
        c.close();
    }

    Log.d("ListData", "" + arr_data);

}


private boolean isValid() {
    if (search_keyword.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter valid key word", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For 1st build we got successful data loaded using list adapter
But after clean project, & Rebuild project showing a no such table expection

Please guide us wr we r going wrong
Advance Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like Clean & Build removes the database. You're re-creating the database, but it contains no tables. So when you're executing statements, it'll throw the no such table exception. Be sure to check beforehand whether the database exists, and if yes whether the necessary tables in it exist. If not, create them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from your print, the table you're referring to is called ListOfAddress, ain't it? your SQL is:

> SELECT_SQL = "SELECT  ROWID AS _id,* **FROM Addresses** where Type LIKE '%" + search_keyword + "%'";

I might be wrong, but I would double check the query.

Comment: but same after rechanging code
SELECT_SQL = "SELECT  ROWID AS _id,* FROM ListOfAddress where Type LIKE '%" + search_keyword + "%'";